# Why is "ssh -t" not working as far as logging in and running a command?

Tags: bash, ssh, foreman

I’m on Mac OS Big Sur and running a virtual Ubuntu 16.04 Linux instance (using vagrant).  I can run the following two commands fine (one to ssh into the virtual server, and the second to run a command within it )…

```
$ ssh myvirtual.local
Warning: Permanently added '10.0.4.19' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Wed Sep 15 16:37:57 2021 from 10.0.4.1
$ foreman start -f Procfile.debug
16:38:26 rails.1      | started with pid 27884
16:38:26 worker.1     | started with pid 27885
16:38:26 scheduler.1  | started with pid 27887
...
```

I would like to be able to combine these two commands, so I tried

```
$ ssh -t myvirtual.local 'foreman start -f Procfile.debug’
Warning: Permanently added '10.0.4.19' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
bash: foreman: command not found
Connection to 10.0.4.19 closed.
```

I’m confused about what other setup I would need to run to have a single command to simulate what I’m doing initially.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Gave that a go, even added "export " in front of the "PATH=" line, restarted my remote server and tried my 'ssh -t' command again but got the same error.

Comment: @zevzek, Gave your suggestion a try but got the error, "/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem foreman (>= 0.a) with executable foreman (Gem::GemNotFoundException)"

Comment: @zevzek, whether `bash` reads `.bashrc` when invoked by sshd depends on how it was compiled. It's the case on Debian and derivatives but not everywhere else as that's not the default (see `SSH_SOURCE_BASHRC` in `config-top.h` in the source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference in this case is that `ssh host` starts your login shell in login mode (`sshd` starts it with `-` prepended to its `argv[0]` which tells the shell it must initialise the login session by reading a `.profile` , `.bash_profile`, `.zprofile`, `.zlogin`, or `.login` (and possibly system ones in `/etc`) startup script depending on the shell implementation), and interactively (in that it issues prompts to get input from you). That's the `rlogin` mode of `ssh`.

While in `ssh -t host 'some shell code'`, `sshd` runs your login shell with `-c` and `some shell code` as argument but without telling it to be a login shell. That shell is also non-interactive, the code is not prompted off you from a terminal. That's the `rsh` mode.

And most probably in your case, the command cannot be found because some directives in session initialisation files to set the `$PATH` variable haven't been run.

Note that not all shells can do both being a login shell and interpret code given as argument.

The `bash` shell can though. `bash` will start as a login shell when it's `argv[0]` starts with `-` but also when passed a `-l` or `--login` option, and then1¹ will still read the login session initialisation files even if passed a command to execute with `-c` (except in POSIX mode).

So here, instead of doing:

```
ssh -t host 'some code'
```

You could do:

```
ssh -t host "exec bash --login -c 'some code'"
```

Which will start another `bash`, but this time as a login shell (which will interpret code in `~/.bash_profile` and possibly some in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d` where the `$PATH` initialisation is) before interpreting `some code`.

Or you could try and locate the file where the `$PATH` definition is made and do:

```
ssh -t host '. /path/to/that/file && some code'
```

That still leaves another difference in that that shell is not interactive and your startup files may decide to behave differently when interactive from when they're not (by checking for the presence of `i` in `$-` or by checking for the presence of a `$PS1` variable).

`bash` doesn't interpret `~/.bashrc` (the interactive shell customisation file) upon startup when run as a login shell, even when interactive (contrary to what happens in most other shells), but most people work around that bizarre design decision by adding a `source ~/.bashrc` in their `~/.bash_profile`. The default `~/.profile` on Debian and derivatives does that by default (only when the shell is `bash` of course).

`bash` doesn't interpret `~/.bashrc` when invoked over ssh by default, but can be configured at compile time to do it using the `SSH_SOURCE_BASHRC` configuration option. Debian and derivatives such as Ubuntu do enable that. So when doing `ssh ubuntu-host 'some code'`, and if your login shell is bash on that machine, the `bash` shell that `sshd` will start will interpret `~/.bashrc` before interpreting `some code`.

So `~/.bashrc` does end-up being interpreted in both the `rlogin` and `rsh` mode, but as noted by @Quasimodo, the default `~/.bashrc` on Debian and Ubuntu has this at the top:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

So, if there's a `$PATH` definition below those lines in there, they will only be interpreted in the `rlogin` mode (where `bash` is interactive, `$-` contains `i` and `~/.bashrc` is sourced by `~/.profile`), and not in the `rsh` mode (where `~/.bashrc` is sourced, but most of its contents is skipped as the shell is not interactive).

---

<sup>¹ in the case of `argv[0]` starting with `-` (as opposed to with `-l`/`--login`), whether it will be treated as a login shell or not when passed a `-c code` depends on whether `bash` was compiled with `NON_INTERACTIVE_LOGIN_SHELLS` enabled or not.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing environment settings as these two scenarios are not always equivalent:

```
ssh remoteHost
someCommand

ssh -t remoteHost someCommand
```

This next command block will give you the set of variables that are missing in your preferred solution (the second format in the two examples, above). You can either add those to your question and I'll complete this one to explain how to set them, or you can use the information yourself to set them.

```
ssh -t myvirtual.local env | grep = | sort >/tmp/env.1
( echo env; echo exit ) | ssh -tt myvirtual.local | grep = | sort >/tmp/env.2
comm -13 /tmp/env.1 /tmp/env.2
```

Abbreviated example output from a system I have here

```
EDITOR=vi
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:...
PAGER=less
PATH=/home/roaima/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
PROMPT_COMMAND_WAS=echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"
SHLVL=1
SSH_CLIENT=192.1.1.9 31996 22
SSH_CONNECTION=192.1.1.9 31996 192.1.1.18 22
TTY=/dev/pts/0
XDG_SESSION_ID=c61
```

This doesn't have anything specific to Ruby or Rails, but it does show that in my case the `PATH` variable is different (you would be able to see the actual values in `/tmp/env.1` and `/tmp/env.2`).

Once you've got this tracked and sorted, you may want to run `foreman` under `screen` or `tmux`, so that it doesn't receive a `SIGHUP` signal when the `ssh` connection is terminated. But I would recommend you start by getting the initial issue resolved before introducing either of these additional tools.